# Como percorrer uma lista em Prolog para encontrar um item específico

Tags: lista, estrutura-de-dados, prolog

Sou iniciante em Prolog e tenho dúvida em como percorrer uma lista.

Tenho um predicado `historico(ra,[i1,i2,i3,...,in])` onde `ra` é o Registro Acadêmico de um aluno e cada `i` é um item, com a forma `item(CM,SM,AN,NT,FQ)`, sendo que `CM` é o código da matéria cursada, `SM` é o semestre, `AN` é o ano, `NT` a nota, e `FQ` a frequência.

Suponha que tenho o seguinte fato:

```
historico(08080808,[item(1,1,2008,3.0,0.77),item(1,2,2008,6.5,0.90),item(5,1,2009,8.0,0.80)]).
```

Preciso produzir a lista dos nomes das matérias extra curriculares cursadas pelo aluno, cujo `RA` será fornecido (o código do curso a ser considerado será fornecido em um segundo parâmetro e a lista produzida deve ser retornada em um terceiro parâmetro); execução pretendida:

```
extra(08080808,1,QUAIS).

QUAIS = [anatomia] (considerando que existe uma materia(5,anatomia,6). )
```

Tenho as seguintes regras já criadas:

```
curso(CODIGOCURSO,NOMECURSO).

materia(CODIGOMATERIA,NOMEMATERIA,CREDITOSMATERIA).

curriculo(CODIGOCURSO,[CODIGOMATERIA1,CODIGOMATERIA2,...,CODIGOMATERIAn).

aluno(RA,NOME).

cursa(RA,CODIGOCURSO).

historico(RA,[ITEM1,ITEM2,...,ITEMn).  (como mostrei anteriormente).
```

Como posso fazer a função `extra(RA,CODIGOCURSO,LISTAMATERIAS)` ?
Pretendo comparar cada item do histórico do aluno, com a matéria e o currículo. Mas como percorrer a lista de itens do histórico do aluno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há duas maneiras de se percorrer uma lista, a mais "natural" - usando recursão, que provavelmente você já conhece - ou através de uma combinação de `member` com `findall`/`bagof`/`setof`. Vou mostrar ambas as formas, pois elas têm vantagens e desvantagens (na legibilidade, principalmente, e *talvez* na performance).

## Recursão

Em primeiro lugar, é necessário determinar se a matéria `M` pertence ao curso `C`:

```
pertence_curso(M,C) :-
    curriculo(C,Lista),
    member(M, Lista).
```

Em seguida, se percorre todas as matérias do aluno verificando se elas pertencem ao curso ou não; se pertence, é incluída na lista, caso contrário você "salta" ela e vai pro próximo:

```
extra(Aluno, Curso, R) :-
    historico(Aluno, Itens),
    percorre_itens(Itens, Curso, R).

% Se acabaram os itens, retorna a lista vazia
percorre_itens([],_,[]).
% Se a matéria pertence ao curso, inclui ela no resultado
percorre_itens([item(CM,_,_,_,_)|Resto], Curso, [Materia|Resultado]) :-
    pertence_curso(CM, Curso),
    !,
    materia(CM, Materia, _),
    percorre_itens(Resto, Curso, Resultado).
% Se ela não pertence ao curso (cláusula anterior falhou), não inclui
percorre_itens([_|Resto], Curso, Resultado) :-
    percorre_itens(Resto, Curso, Resultado).
```

O problema desse método é que ele vai retornar resultados repetidos (no seu exemplo, a matéria `1` foi cursada no primeiro e no segundo semestre, então ela vai ser incluída no resultado final duas vezes). Para contornar isso, você pode ou usar um acumulador (i.e. começa com a lista vazia, e vai inserindo itens nela, mas só insere se ele já não está lá) ou fazer o método normal e no final eliminar os itens repetidos.

## member e setof

A ideia por trás dessa técnica é escolher não deterministicamente um elemento qualquer que satisfaça às condições citadas, e pedir "mais soluções" até que todas as possibilidades sejam esgotadas:

```
materia_extra(Aluno, Curso, Materia) :-
    curriculo(Curso, Materias),
    member(CM, Materias),
    historico(Aluno, Itens),
    member(item(CM,_,_,_,_), Itens),
    materia(CM, Materia, _).
```

E é isso! Escolhi uma matéria na lista de matérias do curso, depois escolhi um item na lista de matérias cursadas pelo aluno cujo código seja o mesmo da matéria escolhida. Esse predicado terá sucesso se tal combinação existe, e retornará apenas um resultado (uma única matéria). Se não for encontrada essa combinação, ele falhará.

É fácil ver que se você chamar `materia_extra` no terminal e ficar pedindo "mais resultados" ele vai te entregar todas as matérias que satisfazem a essa condição, uma por vez. Mas como retornar todas de uma vez, em uma lista sem repetição (i.e. um conjunto)? Aí que entra o `setof`:

```
extra(Aluno, Curso, Lista) :-
    setof(M, materia_extra(Aluno, Curso, M), Lista).
```

Ele vai executar o `materia_extra/3` quantas vezes for possível e, para cada resultado válido, colocar o `M` (especificado no primeiro argumento) na lista `Lista`. No caso do `setof` ele só fará isso se o elemento já não existir lá (o `bagof` funciona igual, só que aceita elementos repetidos; o `findall` é igual ao `bagof`, mas não falha se não houver nenhum resultado, retornando uma lista vazia em vez disso).

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito explicativa, obrigado! Tenho outra dúvida em relação à este mesmo banco de conhecimentos... posso perguntar aqui ou devo abrir uma nova questão?

Comment: Se minha resposta resolveu sua dúvida original, e essa é uma dúvida separada, então é melhor abrir outra pergunta.